# Linux on small SSD and HDD

Tags: system-installation, ssd

Recently I did an installation of Antergos on a netbook with 8GB SSD and 8GB SD card. To fit everything on such small space I've mounted `/` to SSD and `/home` to the SD card and it is working perfectly. Because the SSD was not much faster than the SD Card (it is a very old SSD mounted in Acer One ZG5) I don't have any issues with performance.

Now I am planning to build a small Linux workstation and I already have a Kingston 60GB SSD that I can use but, because 60GB is not a lot I would like to have on it only those components crucial for the performance of the rig and keep everything else on a classic spinning drive.

I am programmer (mostly PHP, JS, Python) so most of my working files will be kept in `/var/www/` .

What do you recommend? Which parts of the system should I mount to SSD and what to HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep your primary `OS` files starting at the `/` directory on the `SSD` `60GB` is a fair amount of space.

Directories I would target for being things you should take off, are things that are written to often, but that you personally don't interact with.

IE: 
`/var` It's a directory whose performance won't directly impact your user performance, but it does get written to constantly in the form of `/var/log` and other related directories. In a completely not noticeable way, this will theoretically extend the life of your SSD.

`/tmp` would be another good choice since again it is something that is written to more frequently, but generally not in a way that means anything to you the user.

Depending on how important performance is for you, I tend to prefer keeping `swap space` on a normal spinning disk as I have always felt like that is just an unnecessary strain on your SSD writes. Although given how fast SSD's are, if you need performance and don't mind the strain, SSD `SWAP` is always an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put everything on the SSD, and then move specific directories as they get too big. I'd predict that `/var/cache` and `/home/<user>/{Documents,Downloads,Pictures,Video,Music}` would be most likely to get out of hand.

You might like to check out [BCache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) in which you put everything on your slow drive, and the OS automatically caches your most frequently used files on the fast drive, but since that appears to require a custom-built kernel, that might be a step too far.

Answer (score 1):

60GB is way enough. That is the SSD drive I have in my machine and I have half of it free.

If you're only going to work with /var/www then create a partition in your HD and mount it there (in my case, my 4TB drive is monted in my /home, which is were the big data is). If you are going to have any other directory with a considerable amount of data just create partitions on your HD and modify your /etc/fstab so that it mounts them on startup.

On the other hand, and since SSD have a limited number of writes (even though they may be a lot) I have created memory partitions for those directories where teporary files are created (/tmp and the like) and mounted those partitions in memory (tmpfs) since I have 16GB or RAM that is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth considering is that some distros take more space than others, and using a distro that demands less space might also help you.

http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/ DSL is an extreme example, requiring only 50 MB of space to install, but searching I'm sure you can find other distros with a  small footprint to give you more of your ssd.